# I've just purchased a domain and getting cold called

Tags: domains

I've just bought a domain and I've just been cold called 7 times today. I would like to know what companies are selling new registrations as leads? I am aware of privatising my information but I'm not paying £4 per annum for the right to be anonymous.

Comment: Do a search for "new domain registration list" - you will find *lots* of companies selling or giving away the information.

Comment: There isn't one company, its hundreds to thousands of companies whom sell whois information. If you want to remain anonymous and don't want private details being published then don't register a domain without private whois since the data contained within a 'whois' check is public domain and there is absolutely no way of stopping it otherwise no matter whom you speak to. The registration data pre-purchase may be sold, but there isn't a online list or anything, most will never admit it in the first place.

Comment: But also, next time... If you want your information to be protected then I recommend that you choose more wisely on the domain registrar. Since several domain registrars now provide private whois at no extra charge, and [Gandi.net for example will never sell or indirectly](https://www.gandi.net/domain/whois/) sell your information.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Are there anymore registrars that don't charge for private whois?

Comment: Google domains also giving free who is protection. Namecheap is also cheapest and alternative option.

Comment: Privacy Whois has a backfire: as long as you use the domain for private purpose it is fine, when you use it for a company or a business it is a demerit for Google (SEO) as you HIDE precious information. Can't be determinate if you are eventually related to spammy websites or in suspicious back link scheme. Beside Google, would you make business with who does not revel his identity? If you have a business you will then want to place name email and telephone number NAP NameAddressPhone in SEO language, to be contacted from customers so your telephone will be there anyway. NAP is good for SEO!